# How to solve Unfold.effects crash?

Tags: julia, unfold

You can see problem on the picture:
UndefVarError: _reference_grid not defined

[image]

Some additional very strange findings:

1. for any reason this function perfectly works in Pluto
2. page for effect function on Unfold manual page shows 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of writing this, Unfold.jl still tries to access `_reference_grid`, which, given that it's not exported by Effects, and has a preceding underscore, it probably never should have.

Checking the commit history of Effects.jl, you'll find that this function was removed in 2022-08-20 https://github.com/beacon-biosignals/Effects.jl/pull/43

Unfold needs to be fixed and updated, or Effects downgraded.

If it works when you use Pluto, then perhaps you are using a different environment there which happens to have a sufficiently old Effects.
I think version 0.1.0 to 0.1.5 should be OK.

```
] add Effects@0.1.5
```

You should consider opening a issue with Unfold.jl

Comment: I guess you have meant Pkg.add(name="Effects", version="0.1.5")